# Can we install WinUSB in Kali linux

Tags: bootable-media, kali-linux, unetbootin

I want to create Bootable USB flash drive for Windows 7. I am trying to do this on Kali Linux. The default program "unetbootin" in kali does not support for Windows.
The another one which i found was "WinUSB", however I am not able to install it in Kali linux.
Any view on this are most welcome...???

Comment: Does this help? http://www.unixmen.com/winusb-create-bootable-windows-usb-linux/

Comment: @MC10 - "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:colingille/freshlight" in kali linux termial says "sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found"

Comment: you could try using ultraiso,whats the problem you were facing while installing or writing os to it could u breif a little?

Comment: @DeepakKumar ppa:colingille/freshlight has recently been updated to support all currently supported versions of Ubuntu, so you shouldn't get the error: `sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found` anymore. There is up-top-date information about how to install Win/USB in Kali Linux in my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the best way to go about getting any old program running in Kali, but it works in this case and is quicker and easier than compiling from source, which I couldn't get to work.

To get the PPA repository working in Kali we need to get add-apt-repository working:

```
apt-get install python-software-properties
apt-get install apt-file
apt-file update
```

This can take a minute or more. Then try searching for add-apt-repository:

```
apt-file search add-apt-repository
```

Which should output something like this:

```
python-software-properties: /usr/bin/add-apt-repository
python-software-properties: /usr/share/man/man1/add-apt-repository.1.gz
```

If it doesn't, like in my first attempt, we need to clean out some old packages

```
apt-get remove python-software-properties
apt-get autoremove
```

Then start from the beginning again and you should get the correct search output. Next we supply the code for add-apt-repository:

```
cd /usr/sbin
nano add-apt-repository
```

Then copy the following into nano, save and exit:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -eq 1 ]
NM=`uname -a && date`
NAME=`echo $NM | md5sum | cut -f1 -d" "`
then
  ppa_name=`echo "$1" | cut -d":" -f2 -s`
  if [ -z "$ppa_name" ]
  then
    echo "PPA name not found"
    echo "Utility to add PPA repositories in your debian machine"
    echo "$0 ppa:user/ppa-name"
  else
    echo "$ppa_name"
    echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/$ppa_name/ubuntu oneiric main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
    apt-get update >> /dev/null 2> /tmp/${NAME}_apt_add_key.txt
    key=`cat /tmp/${NAME}_apt_add_key.txt | cut -d":" -f6 | cut -d" " -f3`
    apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys $key
    rm -rf /tmp/${NAME}_apt_add_key.txt
  fi
else
  echo "Utility to add PPA repositories in your debian machine"
  echo "$0 ppa:user/ppa-name"
fi
```

Quickly fix ownership and permissions:

```
chmod o+x /usr/sbin/add-apt-repository 
chown root:root /usr/sbin/add-apt-repository
```

Then add the PPA repository and install WinUSB:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:colingille/freshlight
apt-get update
apt-get install winusb
```

It's probably a good idea to remove the PPA repository from your sources once you've installed WinUSB to avoid installing other incompatible packages:

```
nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

And delete the last line before closing and saving. The WinUSB GUI is now in the System Tools sub-menu and the command line tools should also work. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

WoeUSB is a tool for creating a bootable USB flash drive used for installing Windows. Native UEFI booting is supported for Windows 7 and later images. WoeUSB is an updated fork of the WinUSB project.

Some third-party installers feature Windows installation images (`/sources/install.wim`) greater than 4GB making FAT32 as target filesystem impossible. NTFS filesystem support has been added to WoeUSB 3.0.0 and later.

#### Installation

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8 
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install woeusb
```

This will install the WoeUSB graphical interface and the WoeUSB command line tool. WoeUSB supports both UEFI and BIOS for FAT32/NTFS/ExFAT USB flash drives.

The WoeUSB GUI is easier to use than the WoeUSB command line tool. Click the radio button to the left of where it says *From a disk image (iso)*, browse to the location of the Windows .iso file, under *Target device* select a USB flash drive, open Disks application and check that the Device name in Disks matches the Target device in WoeUSB (it should be something like /dev/sd**X** where **X** is a letter of the alphabet), and click the *Install* button to install to create a bootable Windows installation media on the USB flash drive.

[image]

[WoeUSB Issues](https://askubuntu.com/a/1243565/)